# Clair de Lune - 2 above notes

Tags: piano, notation

I have a few questions in mind regaring Debussy's Clair de Lune!

What does the line with the number "2" between **B-G** and **A-F** mean?

[image]

And also, should I follow the fingerings for the left hand as shown? It says that I should be playing **F > C** (ascending) in one swift movement which is somewhat difficult to do considering the transtition from thumb (**1**) to pinky (**5**) at **E > F#**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called a Duplet which means two notes in the time of three. So basically you count three beats, but you only play two notes. So in what looks like 9/8 time you will play two notes in the time of a beat.

It is also worth noting that the second chord of the Duplet bar is tied to the first part of the next beat.

[image: Duplet]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this photo! I fully understand what it means now, thanks :) I think this picture is good to know for anyone else who might need help so I'll put it up as the answer!

Comment: What is the reason for using a duplet instead of writing two dotted notes after each other? That would describe the exactly the save rhythm, wouldn't it? Is the reason clarity? In that case I'd prefer the dotted notes.

Comment: There is subtle differences in rhythm, with what you describe

Comment: Remember this is impressionist music, they are all about the unusual rhythms.

Comment: There's no dfference in rhythm between using a duplet or a pair of dotted notes.  There is an opinion that "x notes in the time of y" are conventionally notated as a tuplet, even on the occasions when they COULD be written with normal notes.  Agree, or not!

Comment: @Lii I personally find this notation much quicker to process as "two in the time of three" than two dotted 8ths.  I suppose to some degree it's a matter of convention, when you have a figure like that in a context of compound time.  Perhaps also because it's the opposite of triplet notation in simple time, which pianists see all the time.

Comment: Really any tuplet more compex than "2 vs 3" would be unreadable if it was notated using dotted notes. Multiply the two numbers to get the number of subdivisions required - even "3 vs 4" (think Chopin's Fantaisie Impromptu) would need every beat subdivided into 12 to notate the rhythm within the time signature.

Comment: Lil says that two dotted notes - dotted quavers - would end up playing the same (exactly) as that tuplet. I agree. First with l.h. E, second with l.h. C#. What would be your 'subtle difference in rhythm'?

Comment: @Tim Of course you are right, but my feeling with the tuple as noted is that it's a bit less strict than using dotted notes. Sort of an invitation to bend it with some rubato. Also, dotted notes lead me to think of the second dotted note as being a bit more heavily accented (as if it were beat 4 in 6/8 time) than the second note of the tuple is. This is a personal interpretation, though. Other people might feel entirely differently.

Comment: @BobRodes - the question was actually aimed at Neil Meyer, as he quoted the 'subtle differences'. I would think that however anything is written, a good muso would accent and/or rubato as and when the feeling took them.

Comment: @Tim yeah, I got that it was aimed at Neil. I don't think that there are inherent and fully agreed upon differences in the notations. And of course you are right. But as your latter point relates to notation, I'm saying get a slightly different intuitive communication from each possibility. Not to say that others do and of course any good musician interprets whatever the composer is communicating to me in his or her own way.

Comment: @Tim Another thing is that sometimes one gets the feeling that the notational choice is interfering with the ability to "read" as in interpret the music. In this case the dots wold do that for me. For whatever reason, the tuplets give me a better sense of what I'm feeling the line to be. Perhaps because they give a more specific sense of deviation from the prevailing meter. But I don't see any objective difference between the two notations, subtle or otherwise. They're like two different accepted spellings of the same word.

Answer (score 3):

The '2' means play two notes in the time of the usual three. Rather like a triplet in reverse. A little slower, but even. If you look carefully at where the second note is, compared to the notes under it, you'll see that the r.h. is played at the same time as the C# (l.h.).

Fingering is usually very subjective, as everyone's physiology is different. What's there is a suggestion, but if if doesn't work for you, experiment to find alternatives. Concert pianists will do this all the time.

Answer (score 3):

As for the fingering, I use 4 instead of 5 there, and probably most people would.  A reason not to is that it might be quicker to get 3 on A if 5 is on F# than if 4 is.  Since the passage is pretty rapid, and also pedaled, it's acceptable to make a small jump between 1 and 5, so that might be the motivation for the fingering.  Nevertheless I find 4 easier to use here, and the best finger to get a smooth passage.

Also, though, that looks like a Schirmer edition, and some of the Victorian fingerings in those editions are hopelessly pedantic.  Meaning, fingerings often appear to be chosen because of what was considered "proper technique" in that time period rather than what works best.  Hanon had a finger exercise (number 35) designed to practice little finger over thumb and thumb under little finger, and put a little note "this exercise is of the highest importance."  Well, no it isn't.  The only place I can think of that really requires it is the run near the end of Chopin's Prelude No. 24 in D minor:

[image]

Admittedly, I don't play that passage well, so perhaps the exercise is more important than I think.